# Rails, CKEditor, PostgreSQL, image upload with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ckeditor, carrierwave

When I try to insert an image into my blog I select the Upload tag and select my file and `Send it to Server`.  Then at the URL tab I select `Browse Server` and I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController#index

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "ckeditor_assets" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"ckeditor_assets"'::regclas...
                                    ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
          FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
            ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"ckeditor_assets"'::regclass
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
         ORDER BY a.attnum
```

any ideas?

**EDIT**

I skipped a migration for the above problem.  But I still can't upload a file. I'm getting this error:

```
Started POST "/ckeditor/attachment_files? CKEditor=blog_entry_body&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-24 18:10:29 -0500
Processing by Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000047e3c28 @original_filename="me.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"me.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130524-27036-1g7t9yd>>, "CKEditor"=>"blog_entry_body", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"en"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'M96bQAv-NGdidsn7hypOJA' LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

It looks like it's happening in `Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController#create`.  But I didn't see this controller get generated when I installed the CKEditor gem.  I found in another post that I must `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` but like I said, I don't see `Ckeditor::AttachmentFilesController#create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SQL is what ActiveRecord uses to figure out the structure of a PostgreSQL table and thus the attributes for an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass. The "relation does not exist" error means that you have a `CkeditorAsset` ActiveRecord class (hence the `ckeditor_assets` table name) but not `ckeditor_assets` table. You're missing a migration somewhere, perhaps there is a generator for initializing your CKEditor plugin that you forgot to run.

Comment: Yes, I missed a migration.  But I still can't upload an image.  See above.

Comment: Have you tried monkey patching that controller with the `skip_before_filter` call?